# Draw the line on Captured image

Tags: android, image, android-studio

I captured image from camera I want to preview the image and draw a line by finger on the image with zoom perfection in the image. Can you provide some example code or some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Canvas: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

And more specifically to the drawLine method (it's presented in the link above)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add button with pencil. When button is clicked stop any focus on image and it can be draw lines.
Click [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDrawables/article.html) -it is about bitmap processing